# What does "but more about this presently" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

I was reading an article and came across an unfamiliar phrase for me. Here is the context:

> She would never express regret, let alone offer apology, throughout the months that followed; nor has she done so since. **But more about this presently.**

Then I checked out whether this is a pattern or phrase looking at other written text. I found plenty of usage of "but more about this" either with "presently" or "later".

Another example of usage of "but more about presently"

> Otherwise, you will find it impossible to connect with them and your level of impact will be zero. The very worst thing you can do is to try and take the moral high ground and pressurize them into accepting your values. This will never succeed — **but more about this presently.**

What does this phrase mean exactly?

Comment: It means that she will talk about that subject in the article a little later. [What is the joke in your name? Is there one?]

Comment: Thank you for your response Lambie. So could I say "but more about this presently" equasl " but I'l talk about this more soon" As for my name, it is because I am really into grammar : ) I mean I like to understand sentences in terms of grammar. I've inspired this name from a medieval philosopher John the Grammarian :D

Comment: Yes, exactly. [So wny not spell it **grammarian** because, frankly, that e i in there jangles the nerves...:)]

Comment: Maybe worth noting that in US English, 'presently' usually means 'at this time', or 'currently', whereas in British English it means 'in a short time from now'. Another difference is with 'momentarily', which means (US) 'in a very short time from now', and (British) 'for a very brief time'.